# Squeeze theorem question for limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the following limit using the Squeeze theorem?

$$\lim_{x,y\to 0} \frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

I am not sure what to use for the lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\Bigg|\frac{5xy^2}{x^2+y^2} \Bigg|\le\Bigg|\frac{5xy^2}{y^2} \Bigg|=|5x|$$

Comment: That would be the upper bound, but what about the lower bound? Or can I use 0 for the lower bound?

Comment: $|f(x,y)|\le a \iff f(x,y)\le a \wedge f(x,y)\ge -a$... So your upper bound is $|5x|$ and lower is $-|5x|$. Both go to $0$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $${ x }^{ 2 }-2xy+{ y }^{ 2 }\ge 0\\ { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }\ge 2xy\\ \frac { 1 }{ \left| { x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 } \right|  } \le \frac { 1 }{ \left| 2xy \right|  }  $$ so 
$$
\\ \\ \\ \\ \left| \frac { 5xy^{ 2 } }{ x^{ 2 }+y^{ 2 } }  \right| \le \left| \frac { 5x{ y }^{ 2 } }{ 2xy }  \right| =\frac { 5 }{ 2 } \left| y \right| 
$$

Comment: The final result is fine, but the third inequality is wrong (RHS can be negative).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you for comment,i edited

Answer (score 2):

You could try converting into polar co-ordinates
which gives

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{5r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^2{\theta}}{r^2(\cos^2{(\theta)}+\sin^2(\theta))}=\lim_{r \to 0}5r\cos(\theta)\sin^2{\theta}=0$$

$$|\sin(\theta)| \leq1$$ $$|\cos(\theta)| \leq1$$
$$|\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)| \leq1 $$

Then 
$$|5r\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)| \leq 5r$$

Since $\lim_{r \to 0}(-5r)=\lim_{r \to 0}(5r)=0 $

Thus $r$ is bounded which means our step was justified even though $\theta $

is arbitrary

By Squeeze theorem

$$\lim_{r \to 0}5r\cos(\theta)\sin^2{\theta}=0$$

EDIT : AS mentioned by Yves Daoust,
$$|\sin^2(\theta)\cos(\theta)|\leq \frac{2\sqrt3}{9}$$
which can be verified by taking derivatives and also givs a tighter bound.

Comment: Would the downvoter please give the reason for downvoting?Give me time and a reason so that I can edit to improve my answer..If then also, it is unsuitable...Go ahead and downvote it

Comment: (Not me.) You can tighten the bound by noting $|\sin^2\theta\cos\theta|\le 2/3\sqrt3$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust..How did you arrive at that bound?

Comment: This is elementary search for extrema.

Comment: (Not me) Unnecessary overcomplication. No need to convert to polar every time...

Comment: Well...I was just trying to provide another way in case it becomes useful for the OP in future for other questions..Its always good to have many different tools to solve a problem

Comment: Up-voted, in part, to offset. Fully agreed **RE:** importance of having "many different tools to solve a problem."

Comment: "Thus r is bounded" makes no sense.